# Missing vsperf.exe in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: vsperfmon

Until Visual Studio 2017, there is vsperf.exe.

From Visual Studio 2019, even if I turned on the check box "C++ Profiling Tools" at Visual Studio 2019 Installer ("1" below), but there is no vsperf.exe.

[image: Sorry, I cannot find how to change the language to English.]

Is vsperf.exe deprecated? If it is, what is the alternative?

There are some vsperf*.exe files in Visual Studio 2019 installed directory, such as vsperfmon.exe, vsperfcmd.exe, vsperfsrv.exe, vsperfreport.exe, vsinstr.exe, etc. What are these executable files?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have found:

> You can use VSPerfMon tool to collect performance data for an
> application; typically this tool is launched by VSPerfCmd.exe.
> VSPerfMon displays additional information about process attach or
> detach which is not available by using the VSPerfCmd tool. To view
> this information, start VSPerfMon in a separate window.

See https://github.com/PoulChapman/visualstudio-docs-public-personal/blob/master/docs/profiling/vsperfmon.md

You can launch `VsPerfCmd` like this:

```
VSPerfCmd.exe /start:sample /output:myoutputfile.vsp /launch:myapp.exe /args:"..."
```

Then run the application you want to profile, and finally:

```
VsPerfCmd.exe /Shutdown
```

This will produce the `myoutputfile.vsp` that you can open with Visual Studio.

Here are more options you can choose:

- Coverage
- Concurrency
- Trace

The `Sample` option is probably your best default choice while `Trace` instruments your code and causes your program to slow down but it records the time in each method so it can be more accurate.

See https://github.com/PoulChapman/visualstudio-docs-public-personal/blob/master/docs/profiling/vsperfcmd.md

Here is how you could setup a trace:

```
SET pt="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2022"
%pt%\VSPerfClrEnv /traceon 
%pt%\vsperfcmd /start:trace /output:my_trace_data.vsp
VSPerfNativeSampleApp.exe
%pt%\vsperfcmd /shutdown
%pt%\VSPerfClrEnv /off
%pt%\vsperfreport /summary:all my_trace_data.vsp 
  /symbolpath:"srv*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols"
```

See also https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/520313/Analyzing-profiling-data-from-vsperfcmd